# php, html combobox and textfield

Tags: php, html, combobox, textfield

I made a simple application that have a combobox which is loaded with database value and a textfield which should display text related to combo box selection.
Name        Number
number1     1234
number2     2345
number2     5678
number3     2212

So combo box will have values number1, number2, number3. when user selects number1, i have to load textfield value with 1234 and if number2 is selected 2345,5678.

Below is my code which retrieves from database ... but problem is the value is loaded only when i press enter key instead of clicking submit button...

```
<head>
    <title>Sample Numbers</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
</head>
<body >
    <?php
    $dbname = 'sample_db';
    $db_user = 'xxx';
    $db_pass = 'xxx';
    $host = 'localhost';
    $conn = mysql_connect($host, $db_user, $db_pass);
    mysql_select_db($dbname);
    $query = "select distinct Name from numbers";
    $result = mysql_query($query, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
    ?>
    <center>
        <form name=callsubm>
            <table>
                <?php
                if ($result) {
                ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Group Name:</td>
                        <td><select name="Name" id="Name" onchange="onComboChange();">
                        <?php
                            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                                echo '<option value="' . $row['Name'] . '">' . $row['Name'] . '</option>';
                            }
                         }
                            ?>
                        </select>
                        <?php
                        if (isset($_GET['Name'])) {
                            $array = array();
                            $query = "select Number from numbers where Name='" . $_GET['Name'] . "'";
                            $result = mysql_query($query, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
                            $i = 0;
                            if ($result) {
                                while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                                    $array[] = $row['Number'];
                                    $i++;
                                }
                            }
                            $total_numbers = implode(',', $array);
                        }
                        ?>
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                            function showValues() {
                                var a=new Array();
           <?php
                                  for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
                                       echo "a[$i]='" . $array[$i] . "';\n";
                                  }
    ?>
                                  alert(a.join());
                                  document.getElementById("inTxt").value=a.join();
                            }
                        </script>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Numbers :</td>
                    <td ><input name=inTxt id=inTxt type="text" size="15"></td>
                    <td><input type="button" id="callBtn" name="callBtn" value="submit" onclick="showValues()" ></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </center>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function onComboChange() {
         groupName=document.getElementById("Name").value;
         alert("Selected Group:" + groupName);
    }
    </script>
</body>
```

How to solve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yeah, click on the little check box if the answer worked for you.

Comment: Could you please post the generated html source code, too?

Answer (score 1):

If you need a submit button, but it doesn't have to be a `button`, use an `<input type="submit">`.

Thus, change your html to:

```
<input type="submit" id="callBtn" name="callBtn" value="submit" onclick="showValues()" >
```

(You can omit the `value="submit"` if you don't query that value in php...)

**When to use a button:**
If you want the text being displayed on the submit button to be different to the value of the submit, you use a button:

```
<button type="submit" id="callBtn" name="callBtn" onclick="showValues()" 
    value="valueToBeSubmitted">textToBeDisplayed</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the type to submit on your submit button, rather than using button as the type:

```
<input type="submit" id="callBtn" name="callBtn" value="submit" onclick="showValues()" >
```

Comment: But the php $total_numbers is generated only when i press the enter and if i pass it to javascript only empty string is returned. i don know where am going wrong

Comment: Can you try to explain this in more detail by editing your question? Esp. what you mean by "pass it to javascript"?

Comment: Thanks Martin. I Solved this issue using ajax. I passed the combo value as request to another php file and returned a string response.